# How to set up the chef environment, running Django, to send mail

Tags: python, linux, django, chef-infra

I have a chef environment on my system, which is running Ubuntu Linux 12.10. I cannot seem to get chef configured correctly to do send_mail in Django/Python. Where do I look. What do I need to configure chef to do this? My Python/Django code is fine.

Comment: You mean `send_mail` doesn't work? Any error? Are you using any custom mail backend? Any SMTP service is being used?

Comment: Correct. The code works on the simple python/django server I used first on my other Linux system, but when  migrated the code to this chef environment it does not work. It must be that chef is not set-up or configured correctly for smtp... ? I am new to chef and the docs...well...I can't find a thing except a little about Pony...?

Comment: 1. configure send_mail by hand. 2. memorize steps or better write them down. 3. rewrite the steps using chef resources. Where are you currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure postfix is set up in chef first. If not, log into your VM were chef is running:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Then gedit, nano, VIM, or whatever you prefer into main conf file:

```
sudo vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Finally, see what your relay host is set to and alte it to the email bo you wnt the contact emails to go:

```
relayhost = mail.your-admin-email.com
```

See if that doesn't fix the issue for u.

Comment: That fixed it...ty..just now got around to it...also had another error Python related...but that was the big hold up